# Perl STDOUT redirected to a pipe, no output after calling sleep()

Tags: perl, pipe, stdout, sleep, tee

I'm having problems with Perl on Windows (both ActivePerl and Strawberry), when redirecting a script STDOUT to a pipe, and using sleep(). Try this:

```
perl -e "for (;;) { print 'Printing line ', $i++, \"\n\"; sleep(1); }"
```

This works as expected. Now pipe it to Tee (or some file, same result):

```
perl -e "for (;;) { print 'Printing line ', $i++, \"\n\"; sleep(1); }" | tee
```

There's no output at all, tee captures nothing. However, the perl script is still running, only there's nothing on STDOUT until the script finishes, and then all output is dumped to tee. Except, if the STDOUT buffer fills the script might hang.

Now, if you remove the sleep(call), the pipe works as expected! What's going on?

I found a workaround; disabling the STDOUT buffering with $|=1 makes the pipe work when using the sleep, but... why? Can anyone explain and offer a better solution?

Comment: where is your `tee` program from?  and what do you mean by "might hang"?  have you had it hang?

Comment: I tried two different GNU tee binaries, and even a third one developed in-house in C#, same behavior. Also, just redirecting to a file with ">" gives the same behavior. Without sleep all is fine, after it there's no output until the script finishes. And yes, we have scripts that run all day long and we come back to find them hung.

Comment: The only thing that the `sleep` changes is that your script does not finish immediately and thus has its buffer flushed. This has nothing to do with the `tee`. However, i as well have experienced that apps with constant output suffer from buffering. In our case the OS kept buffering so long, waiting for a decrease in output, that when it finally had to flush and `sync`, it would often take too long and the buffer would overflow because output stayed high. We forced a `sync` every 4 minutes or so to fix that. `$|=1` may not fix that, you may have to actually call `sync` periodically.

Comment: I should add that in our case it was not the buffer of STDOUT but the disk that tried to buffer too much.

Comment: Ok. But why does it work fine with a select(undef, undef, undef, 1), but not with sleep (1) ?

Comment: DeVadder, this happens on scripts that run on infinite loops, and generate thousands of stdout lines. Normal script output is captured by tee just fine, but add that sleep () and you don't see a single line anymore, for hours.

Comment: Turns out the hanging was unrelated to this issue. The issue was the IO buffering getting flushed out if the script calls some external shell command/executable, but not otherwise. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are suffering from buffering. Add `$| = 1;` to unbuffer STDOUT.

All file handles except STDERR are buffered by default, but STDOUT uses a minimal form of buffering (flushed by newlines) when connected to a terminal. By substituting the terminal for a pipe, normal buffering is reinstated.

Removing the `sleep` call doesn't change anything except to speeds things up. Instead of taking minutes to fill up the buffer, it takes milliseconds. With or without it, the output is still written in 4k or 8k blocks (depending on your version of Perl).

Comment: I did say that I had found that particular "fix" in my question above. That still doesn't explain why adding the sleep call makes it behave differently.

Comment: It's not adding the sleep call, it's adding `|tee`, and I did explain why that makes a difference. `sleep` is not a factor here; the same thing happens with or without it. It just happens a lot faster without sleep.

Comment: It's not tee, and while it is for sure related to buffering,  that s not the whole story. Sleep is definitely changing the behavior, and I'd like to know why. If you use perl's sleep (), output stops completely (try to write 100 lines, not a single one is printed). If you replace the sleep for an equivalent select (undef, undef, undef, 1) it works fine. If you replace it with a `sleep 1` (backticks) it also works fine. Please try it out. ..

Comment: No, the output is sent 4k or 8k at a time with or without sleep. It's just way faster without sleep. You'd need to wait about 500 or 1000 seconds to accumulate enough output with `sleep(1)`.

Comment: Thanks Ikegami, but please go and test it, on Windows. I tried with much more than 64k (as I suspected that might be the buffer size limit) and still there was no output. Again, remove or replace the sleep call and all is well. Why? And please go and run the tests, no point in keeping this discussion until you  understand what I m taking about.

Comment: I am. I still have to wait 7 minute for the buffer to fill up if it's a 4k buffer.

Comment: Yup, worked as I expected. After ~7 minutes, 4k of output came out. `sleep` has no affect but to slow things down.

Comment: Exactly the same behaviour with `select(undef,undef,undef,1)`.

Comment: (Oops, I have an 8k buffer, but it came out to the predicted time cause the output was twice as long as I thought it was.)

Comment: more important question: what shell is this?

Comment: @ysth, `cmd` on Win7, launching ActivePerl 5.16.3 for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread and cygwin's `tee`. Why do you ask?

Comment: sorry, meant to have commented on the question, not your answer.  but I'm not surprised that cygwin's tee might act differently than what sounds like a msvcrt based tee does.

Comment: @ysth, I don't see why. You'll see exactly the same behaviour using `perl -pe1` instead of `tee`. There's nothing OS-specific about Perl's buffering.

Comment: OK, I re-tested and you're right, select() does have the same behaviour, and it is buffering. Behaviour changes however when calling an external/shell command (with backtick, for instance). This seems to force buffer flush, so it appears to work normally. This explains the issue I was seeing, since I was also testing with `sleep` and `timeout`, which are two external executables. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I knew that reading from STDIN forces a flush, but I didn't know about backticks, though. cool